# Spring Integration Web Service 405 Error

Tags: spring-integration

I've been asked to do a prototype, converting a working web service that uses a Spring enabled JAX-WS endpoint to using Spring Integration instead, and I've been told to use xml configuration as much as possible. I stripped down the application until just the relevant web service elements remain, and I've created a couple of new spring xml config files as needed. While it compiles fine, when I deploy to a JBoss container and then try to invoke it using SoapUI, I get a HTTP 405 response, and there's nothing in the JBoss console to indicate that the request was even received, though the server log indicates the new gateway and service activator was setup correctly and is running. I can't find anything remotely relevant in any of the Spring documentation I've read, and none of the code examples I've pulled from Github address configuring the web service to run in an actual J2EE server.
I'm at a complete loss as to what I should be looking at. Here are my spring config files:

springContext-main.xml (I can't use applicationContext.xml in the real app due to pre-existing contraints)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <!-- <bean class="com.bofa.ecom.intfacade.web.ApplicationConfiguration"/> -->

    <bean id="reconDao" class="com.bofa.ecom.intfacade.snf.recon.dao.ReconDAOImpl">
        <!-- <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/> -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="reconServiceHelper" class="com.bofa.ecom.intfacade.snf.recon.service.helper.ReconServiceHelperImpl">
        <constructor-arg ref="reconDao"/>
    </bean>

    <import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/recon-ws.xml"/>

</beans>
```

recon-ws.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-1.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd">

<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory"/>

    <import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/inbound-gateway-config.xml" />

<sws:dynamic-wsdl id="reconWsdl" portTypeName="reconGateway" locationUri="/reconService"
                      targetNamespace="http://intfacade.cpm.ecom.bofa.com/">
        <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/recon.xsd"/>
    </sws:dynamic-wsdl>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.UriEndpointMapping">
    <property name="defaultEndpoint" ref="reconGateway"></property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

inbound-gateway-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int-ws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws/spring-integration-ws.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <int:channel id="recon-input"/>

    <int-ws:inbound-gateway id="reconGateway" request-channel="recon-input"/>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="recon-input" method="saveArrangementApplicationDetails">
        <bean id="arrangementApplicationReconService" class="com.bofa.ecom.intfacade.snf.recon.service.ArrangementApplicationReconServiceImpl">
            <constructor-arg ref="reconServiceHelper"/>
        </bean>
    </int:service-activator>

</beans>
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.
Edit: I've narrowed it down to what I think is a configuration problem with either SI or Spring-ws. I can't find a complete SI + Spring-ws example that uses XML configuration to figure out what I'm missing or doing wrong. I've added my spring ws config file above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

405 is Method Not Allowed - it appears you are doing a GET (or something else) rather than a POST.

If you believe you are POSTing, take a look with a network monitor (wireshark, or the built-in tcp/ip monitor in eclipse).

You may also be hitting the wrong URL; I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging on the server.

If you still can't figure it out, post the log someplace such as a gist.

Comment: There isn't anything I can find that would prevent the methods from being called. I was able to determine that my url was incorrect, and that I needed to add some spring-ws configuration as well, though I'm still getting the same result. My assumption at the moment is that I'm getting the result because my configuration still isn't correct. I may post the logs and more code elsewhere if I don't figure it out soon.

Comment: FWIW; I tested with the [sample app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/ws-inbound-gateway) yesterday and was able to get a 405 by using the http sample to invoke the WS with a GET.

Comment: I was correct - turns out I needed to add some more configuration to the spring web services file and adjust the value of the locationUrl attribute in the dynamic-wsdl tag. Turns out Spring is very sensitive about the value that gets put in there.